# Is there an IMAP email client on OSX (other than Mail.app) that allows you to hyperlink to mail messages?

Tags: macos, email, imap

I'm looking for a new email client for OSX because Mail.app seems to occasionally lose messages in my Sent folder.

One feature I really like with Mail.app is that you can store hyperlinks to individual email messages. You can see this behavior by dragging an email to a program that supports hyperlinks, like VoodooPad, it creates a link that looks like `message://<4AB7A2D1.1090703@example.com>`.

Are there any other email clients on OSX that support creating and following these kinds of hyperlinks to individual mail messages?

Comment: You are not by any chance using Gmail in Mail.app? (As a side note: one can also get this hyperlink from attachments one saved from an email; see http://superuser.com/questions/7337/how-do-i-copy-a-link-to-a-mail-app-message-without-using-drag-and-drop/17361#17361)

Comment: No, I'm not using Mail.app to connect to Gmail.

Comment: Also, if the attachment is saved using thunderbird, "mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms" doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Mail.app exclusively even before my organization supported it in Snow Leopard (darn Microsoft Exchange Servers!) and I've noticed that when I immediately send a message such as a reply, I can't click the little "replied to" icon next to the original email I responded to to open my reply.

This has to do with the fact that my email has not been received in the Sent folder and therefore does not yet exist.  Waiting for the one-minute auto check of incoming mail or manually clicking the Get Mail button has always resolved this issue for me.

Beyond that, you can set "automatically CC/BCC myself" in the Preferences under the Composing section.  I'd recommend in that case to also add a rule that sorts these emails to a secondary folder, otherwise you'll be knee-deep in your messages to other people.  Then again, with the Threading option enabled, maybe that would bring some good context to messages received where the remote party failed to include what I said to them (and I'm forgetful at times).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better choice of Mail clients, and this could be part of a larger problem on your computer, or maybe just a rule in Mail.app or server side (if this is an IMAP account) that files them elsewhere or deletes them.

It could also be indicative of problems on your hard drive. I'd recommend running Disk Utility and Disk Warrior.  Also, in Mail if you select the Sent Folder and then choose the Mail Menu there is an option called Rebuild. That will make sure Mail is displaying all of the messages that are in that folder.