# Hyperlink (or at least easily searchable ID) **to** mail

Tags: thunderbird, metadata

I wondered if there is a possibility to create a link (or similar, see below)  in a word processor pointing *to* a message, event etc. in Thunderbird on Win or Ubuntu. So far I found (and did not solve the issue):

- drag & drop Thunderbird message into MS Word: places (copy of) message itself, no link (and hence no context of linked messages, can be big b/o attachments...).
- drag & drop message into Libre Writer: opens box where I can check "link", even "DDE" (seemed promising...), but this is just an "insert section" box, which inserts only an empty section. Not sure how this is meant to work on drag&drop...
- This [Q/A](https://superuser.com/questions/7337/how-do-i-copy-a-link-to-a-mail-app-message-without-using-drag-and-drop/17361#17361) seems exactly what I want, but works only for Mac (need Win or Linux) ("How do I copy a link to a Mail.app message without using drag-and-drop?")
- Read sth. about ADS and metadata that is attached to files from mail/internet and contains the file source, but did not find a possibility to use it to actually locate the original mail.

What I want to achieve is, e.g. in a ToDo list or project summary, refer to external material such as mails, where more information is stored that exeeds the scope of the ToDo list/project summary, without writing down folder, date etc. manually.

**UPDATE** (thanks to user1138 for the hint!): Thunderbird seems to work with GUIDs, also based on Mozilla pages [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Generating_GUIDs), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIUUIDGenerator), [3](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624535) and [Mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2902379). However, I could not figure out if these are used as needed for individual messages (or sth. completely different - sorry for my lack of understanding), at least I could not find sth. suggestive in the mail source view, so it might be wrong. But if true: how would one access (find and search) them?

**Update 2:** To relax requirements a little bit: A useful solution would be a classical hyperlink, but if not possible also anything that is easily and uniqulely searchable, e.g. a GUID or similar I can search for in TB (else than e.g. subject, which is not unique). I know I can place extended search terms (almost unique by sender, subject, time), but I want to avoid writing down a lot of stuff in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Windows supported Hyperlinks to Outlook "stuff" (more info at [davidtan.org](https://www.davidtan.org/create-hyperlinks-to-outlook-messages-folders-contacts-events/)) and a similar question to yours was answered for Outlook [here](https://superuser.com/questions/71786/can-i-create-a-link-to-a-specific-email-message-in-outlook).

But I'm not aware of/nor could I find any such equivalent capability (Paths/GUID's) for Thunderbird.

So beyond writing your own program/Thunderbird Add-on, I think maybe your easiest approach would be to right-click on individual e-mails, select Convert To, Tasks... and then Title each one in a way that references the corresponding ToDo list item.

That, or use Windoze/LookOut! ;-D